# Flask SQLAlchemy: TypeError: 'Flask' object is not iterable

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am attempting to create a Flask app where users can register / login and have their own page (following a tutorial on YT) - I am quite new to this and am struggling to understand the error message that I am receiving.

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mmacp\PycharmProjects\cfg_project\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "C:\Users\mmacp\PycharmProjects\cfg_project\website\__init__.py", line 25, in create_app
    create_database(app)
  File "C:\Users\mmacp\PycharmProjects\cfg_project\website\__init__.py", line 32, in create_database
    db.create_all(app)
  File "C:\Users\mmacp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 868, in create_all
    self._call_for_binds(bind_key, "create_all")
  File "C:\Users\mmacp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 837, in _call_for_binds
    for key in keys:
TypeError: 'Flask' object is not iterable
```

**main.py:**

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

****init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path


db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'kdxhfds iefhsdbf'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    from .models import User, Posts

    create_database(app)

    return app


def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('website/' + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app)
        print('Created Database!')
```

**models.py**

```
from website import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class Posts(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(500))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')) # refs the User table


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    surname = db.Column(db.String(150))
    fav_team = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship('posts')
```

I have tried to reformat the database User and Posts classes and have attempted some minor tweaks which haven't helped - currently at a bit of a loss as to what I should do next.

Usually I can eventually figure these things out but my heads a bit fried!!

Comment: Try removing the `app` from `create_all` for your database. It's not needed. Take a look here; https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/

Comment: Thank you I actually ended up adding to my create_app() funtion:

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

which has solved it!

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this by adding a piece of code to the create_app() function in the **init**.py file:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'kdxhfds iefhsdbf'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///databse.db'
    db.init_app(app)

    ***with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()***
```